# Beamer: don't enumerate the first section in the TOC

Tags: beamer

I have several sections in a Beamer document, starting the section number 1 on the second section. For that I use

```
\tableofcontents[firstsection=2]
```

but the first section has the number zero. So, I would like the first section without number. Soomething like the option `\frontmatter` for the book class. Any idea?

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
\tableofcontents[firstsection=2]
\end{frame}

\section{no-numerated section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}

\subsection{First sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}

\subsection{First sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Third section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, using a redefinition of the internal command `\beamer@sectionintoc` implemented in the `beamerbasetoc.sty` file; with the redefinition, no number is typeset in the ToC if it's less than `1`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@sectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth>0%
  \ifnum#4=\beamer@showpartnumber%
  {
  \beamer@saveanother%
  \gdef\beamer@todo{}%
  \beamer@slideinframe=#1\relax%
  \expandafter\only\beamer@tocsections{\gdef\beamer@todo{%
      \beamer@tempcount=#5\relax%
      \advance\beamer@tempcount by\beamer@sectionadjust%
      \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
      \edef\inserttocsectionnumber{\the\beamer@tempcount}\else
      \edef\inserttocsectionnumber{}\fi%
      \def\inserttocsection{\hyperlink{Navigation#3}{#2}}%
      \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=#1\beamer@toc@cs\else\beamer@toc@os\fi}%
      {
        \ifbeamer@pausesections\pause\fi%
        \ifx\beamer@toc@ooss\beamer@hidetext
          \vskip1.5em
        \else
          \vfill
        \fi
        {%
          \hbox{\vbox{%
              \def\beamer@breakhere{\\}%
              \beamer@tocact{\ifnum\c@section=#1\beamer@toc@cs\else\beamer@toc@os\fi}{section in toc}}}%
         \par%
        }%
      }%
    }
  }%
  \beamer@restoreanother%
  }
  \beamer@todo%
  \fi\fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
\tableofcontents[firstsection=2]
\end{frame}

\section{no-numerated section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{First Section}

\subsection{First sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}

\subsection{First sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second sub-section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Third section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added this code to `beamer`: it will be in the next release, probably once TeX Live starts updating again.