# Beamer starred section formatting in the TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, starred-version

I am writing a `beamer` presentation and I want the structure (and the `.toc`) to be:

> Introduction
>   1. Section 1
>   2. Section 2
>   3. Section 3
>   Conclusion

Therefore, I used the starred version of the section command (`\section*{Intro}`) and the `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Intro}` to add it to the `toc`.

The problem is: the formatting of the Intro title and the Section 1, 2... titles in the `.toc` are different.

Any idea how to fix that?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are writing the wrong contents line to the `toc`. Open the `.toc` file and compare what you write with what `beamer` writes.

Comment: This is what the .toc file looks like :  `\beamer@endinputifotherversion {3.36pt}
    \contentsline {section}{Intro}
    \beamer@sectionintoc {2}{Section 1}{3}{0}{1}
    \beamer@sectionintoc {3}{Section 2}{4}{0}{2}
    \beamer@sectionintoc {4}{Section 3}{5}{0}{3}
    \contentsline {section}{Conclusion}`

I tried to change the `\contentsline` command to `\beamer@sectionintoc` with no luck. Any hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dirty hack and the artificial toc-entries do not provide links to the sections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\vskip1.5em\hskip1.2em\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}Intro}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\vskip1.5em\hskip1.2em\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find a answer in this post.

[Beamer: don't enumerate the first section in the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115638/beamer-dont-enumerate-the-first-section-in-the-toc)

One problem remains : with this solution, there is still a empty square/ball (depending of what you choose) in front of the "unnumbered" section.

I am not very familiar with the code exposed in the answer ; is there a way to remove this square/ball marker ?

Comment: Perhaps better edit this in your question, since problems remain?